# Applying Style in React Native View Component

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native. I am trying to position a logo on the right side of a navbar but when trying this, it is not working for me and I don't understand why.

```
export const LogosStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    navbar: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
    },
    LogoAddSquare: {
        width: 24,
        height: 24,
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        // position: 'absolute', //none of these worked
        // right: 0,
        // alignItems: "flex-end",
        // justifyContent: "flex-end", 
    },
})
```

Also tried inline styling and nothing although absolute and right are giving me the result I need on the console

```
export function Dashboard(props) {
    const [showSidebar, setSidebar] = useState(true)

    return <Row style={DashboardStyles.main}>
        {showSidebar && <Sidebar>
            {props.menuItems.map(item =>
                <SidebarItem {...item} key={item.to} />
            )}
        </Sidebar>}

        <Column style={DashboardStyles.main}>
            <ProfileBar>
                <View style={LogosStyles.navbar}>
                    {<LogoArrowLeft />}
                    <CheckBox
                        label="Menu"
                        checked={showSidebar}
                        onChange={setSidebar}
                    />
                    {<LogoAddSquare
                        style={LogosStyles.LogoAddSquare}
                        /* style={{ position: "absolute", right: 0 }} */ />} 
                </View>

            </ProfileBar>
            {props.children}
        </Column>
    </Row>
}
```

Comment: could you please provider some sample code via [snack](https://snack.expo.io/)? It is hard to understand the problem with a partial solution

Comment: Here, hope that helps https://snack.expo.io/@pandassi/f08eee

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, we need to give below styles to the parent element,

Try like below,

```
navbar: {
   flex: 1,
   flexDirection: "row",
   justifyContent: "flex-end", // This will move your logo horizontally in right direction
   alignItems: "flex-end", // This will move your logo vertically in down direction, You can give "center" to look nice
},
LogoAddSquare: {
   width: 24,
   height: 24,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by adding an empty View class for spacing, which needs to be defined for each component (there is no heritage in React-Native). I was trying to apply justify-content in a too empty element, as everything in React-Native is in a FlexBox, so I needed Flex to define the proportion of elements.

```
        <Row style={DashboardStyles.main}>
            {showSidebar && <Sidebar>
                {props.menuItems.map(item =>
                    <SidebarItem {...item} key={item.to} />
                )}
            </Sidebar>}

            <Column style={DashboardStyles.main}>
                <ProfileBar>
                    {<LogoArrowLeft />}
                    <CheckBox
                        label="Menu"
                        checked={showSidebar}
                        onChange={setSidebar}
                    />
                    <Flex /> {/* This is a shortcut equivalent of 
                              <View style={{flex: 1}} />  that was set up 
                              for this purpose (with a ratio 1:1) */}

                    {<LogoAddSquare
                        style={LogosStyles.LogoAddSquare} />}

                </ProfileBar>
                {props.children}
            </Column>
        </Row>
```